# How to store JSON decodable values into Coredata using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I am trying to load `JSON` Data into `CoreData`. Here, I used JSON `structure` for decodable and after that I am trying to fetch the `decodable` Data into CoreData. I don’t know how to use decodable with `iterate` the data and fetching into coredata. Below code I tried, but not getting proper result. Please help me to resolve this.

**My JSON**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "20",
            "name": "ar1"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "name": "ar2"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "name": "ar3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My Structure For JSON**

```
struct userList: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [userData]
}

struct userData: Codable {
    let id, name: String
}
```

**My Coredata Entity**

```
var users = [User]() // User is my entity name
```

**JSON Codable and Try  ing to Load Into CoreData**

```
do {
       let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(userList.self, from:data) // here I am dong mistakes.
       let status = result.status
       if status == true {
           let newPerson = User(context: self.context)
           newPerson.id = "" // Cant able to get values
           newPerson.name = ""
           self.users.append(newPerson)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
             }
            } else {
               print(error)
             }

    } catch {
         print(error)
}
```

Comment: @vadian can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

To be able to decode JSON directly into Core Data classes you have to adopt Decodable

- Implement two extensions to be able to pass the managed object context via the `JSONDecoder`

  ```
  extension CodingUserInfoKey {
      static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
  }

  extension JSONDecoder {
      convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
          self.init()
          self.userInfo[.context] = context
      }
  }
  ```
- In `User` adopt `Decodable` and add `CodingKeys` and the required `init(from` method

  ```
  public class User: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

      private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, id }

      public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
          guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Error: with managed object context!") }
          let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)!
          self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
          let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
          name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
          id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
      }
  ...
  ```
- Now you need only one umbrella struct for the root object. Once again please name structs always with starting uppercase letter

  ```
  struct Root: Decodable {
      let status: Bool
      let data: [User]
  }
  ```
- To decode the JSON use the custom initializer, the `User` instances are inserted automatically into the database

  ```
  do {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder(context: context) // context is the NSManagedObjectContext instance 
      let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
      if result.status {
         print("success")
         try context.save()
      }  
  catch { print(error)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try my end and update you here.