# How to convert stored values to JSON format using Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I am trying to convert stored `coredata` values to `JSON` format and the JSON format value need to assign a single variable, because this generated JSON I need to send to server. Below code I tried to get coredata stored values but don’t know how to generate JSON required format.

**Getting values from coredata**

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let  dateCreated = results as! [Userscore]
            for _datecreated in dateCreated {
                print("\(_datecreated.id!)-\(_datecreated.name!)") // Output: 79-b \n 80-c \n 78-a
            }
   } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
}
```

**Need to Convert Coredata Value to Below JSON format**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "20",
            "name": "a"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "name": "b"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "name": "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I guess it's [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237755/coredata-object-to-json-in-swift-3/46237971)

Comment: @VadimNikolaev It is not duplicate I am asking from the line `print("\(_datecreated.id!)-\(_datecreated.name!)")` to make a JSON format and assign to a variable for server pass.

Comment: `CoreData object to JSON in Swift 3`, that's the title of the linked question. Isn't your goal too?

Comment: According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629695/how-to-store-json-decodable-values-into-coredata-using-swift) adopt also `Encodable`. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @vadian I just want to make this `print("\(_datecreated.id!)-\(_datecreated.name!)")` values to required JSON format. Can I store it into array and making this?

Comment: Yes, you can specify any arbitrary format you want.

Comment: @vadian Yes. that is I am expecting. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoreData object to JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237755/coredata-object-to-json-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest is to convert your object(s) to either dictionaries or arrays (depending on what you need).

First you need to be able to convert your `Userscore` to dictionary. I will use extension on it since I have no idea what your entity looks like:

```
extension Userscore {

    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any]? {
        guard let id = id else { return nil }
        guard let name = name else { return nil }
        return [
            "id": id,
            "name": name
        ]
    }

}
```

Now this method can be used to generate an array of your dictionaries simply using `let arrayOfUserscores: [[String: Any]] = userscores.compactMap { $0.toDictionary() }`.

Or to build up your whole JSON as posted in question:

```
func generateUserscoreJSON(userscores: [Userscore]) -> Data? {
    var payload: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
    payload["status"] = true
    payload["data"] = userscores.compactMap { $0.toDictionary() }
    return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload, options: .prettyPrinted)
}
```

This will now create raw data ready to be sent to server for instance

```
var request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
request.httpBody = generateUserscoreJSON(userscores: userscores)
```

Comment: I am getting confusion where I want to use `Userscore` extension  also when I need to call `generateUserscoreJSON`?

Comment: from where I need to call this `generateUserscoreJSON(editmilestone: [EditMilestone]) -> Data?`

Comment: @Tim I can not advise you on that without you providing your code where you try sending data to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties of an `Encodable` to make this happen. This has the added benefit of not resorting to the `Any` type.

For the JSON, you could use the following types:

```swift
struct JSONMessage: Encodable {
    var status: Bool
    var data: [JSONDataEntry]
}

struct JSONDataEntry: Encodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

Then you can adjust your do/try/catch as follows:

```swift
do {
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let  dateCreated = results as! [Userscore]
    // *starting here*
    let data = dateCreated.map { JSONDataEntry(id: String($0.id!), name: $0.name!) }
    let status = true   // <- not sure where status comes from, so adding here
    let message = JSONMessage(status: status, data: data)
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(message)
    if let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        // do something with the JSON string
        print(json)
    }
    // *ending here*
} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.debugDescription)
}
```