# How to store two values with two different key into array or dictionary using Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to store two different values like `id` and `name` into array or dictionary with a key and value. Once, I store need to convert a JSON format like below. How to achieve this?

**My Values For Storing into Array or Dictionary**

```
do {
     let  dateCreated = results as! [Student]
     for _datecreated in dateCreated {
        print("\(_datecreated.id!)-\(_datecreated.name!)") // This two Value I need store into array or dictionary and convert like below JSON format
     }
   } catch let err as NSError {
      print(err.debugDescription)
   }
```

**Required JSON Format**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "20",
            "name": "a"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "name": "b"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "name": "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rob `print("\(_datecreated.id!)-\(_datecreated.name!)")` these two values I need to convert to above mentioned JSON format and that JSON format need to assign a variable for server passing.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512839/create-json-in-swift/40901241

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758398/11760652) on your related/duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you ...:)

```
var data = [Any]()
// call this function on time of get data or adding data 
func info (id : Int , name : String){
    var information = [id : name]
    data.append(information)
}

//this function will generate final formate 

func create_formate() -> [String:Any]{
    var final_formate = [String:Any]()
    final_formate["status"] = true
    final_formate["data"] = data

    return final_formate
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try my end and update you here.

Comment: sure I will wait for your right mark... :)

Comment: if I want to send without status and data then how can I do it?

Comment: u mean blenk.. ?

Comment: If I am trying to send server, its posting like this ` \”name\”:\”(\\n        {\\n        id = 78;\\n        name = a;\\n    }\\n)\"}}")` but Need to send properly like this `[[“name”: "a", "id": "78"]]`

Answer (score 1):

**1.Array:** 
You cant use Array to store JSON. because it can store only the same data type values. JSON has different Data types like String, Int, Boolean, Array.

**2.Dictionary:**
You can use an Array of Dictionary to store your student data inside JSON. JSON structure uses  Dictionary { "key" : "value"} and Array [element1,element2].If you observe this pattern you can store any JSON data inside Dictionary

```
class Student{
    let id : String
    let name : String
    init(id : String , name :String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}


    let data1 = Student(id: "20", name: "a")
    let data2 = Student(id: "21", name: "b")
    let data3 = Student(id: "22", name: "c")
    let status = true
    let dataArray = [data1,data2,data3]
    // Use array of dictory because Each student details are in a Dictoray. 
    var dataDictArray = [[String:String]]()
    for data in dataArray{
         var dataDict = [String : String]()
        dataDict["id"] = data.id
        dataDict["name"] = data.name
        dataDictArray.append(dataDict)
    }
    var jsonDict = [String : Any]()
    jsonDict["status"] = status

    jsonDict["data"] = dataDictArray

    print(jsonDict)
```

**output:-**

```
(lldb) p jsonDict
([String : Any]) $R4 = 2 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = "data"
    value = 3 values {
      [0] = 2 key/value pairs {
        [0] = (key = "name", value = "a")
        [1] = (key = "id", value = "20")
      }
      [1] = 2 key/value pairs {
        [0] = (key = "name", value = "b")
        [1] = (key = "id", value = "21")
      }
      [2] = 2 key/value pairs {
        [0] = (key = "id", value = "22")
        [1] = (key = "name", value = "c")
      }
    }
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "status"
    value = true
  }
}
```

Hope you got better understanding of storing JSON inside Dictory.